# Can access localhost:3000 but not 127.0.0.1:3000 on mac machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, web-applications, configuration, localhost

I have rails app running on my mac machine, and am able to access localhost:3000 but can not access 127.0.0.1:3000

in `/etc/hosts` I have

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Do I need to add any more settings? or am I missing anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your Rails server to 0.0.0.0 . This way your application will be available at:

`lvh.me:3000`
`localhost:3000`
`your_ip:3000`
`127.0.0.1:3000`

`rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Yeah that worked, but do I need to do it everytime when I start rails server?

Comment: Yes, don't see why should that be a problem though. If you do rails s and tab it it should autocomplete your command. Alternatively, you can always alias the command. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind Rails server with `-b` option. This way you can use `Your IP` , `127.0.0.1` & `lvh.me`

Run this

`rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

Here is a very good tutorial for Rails basic commands with other options

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-rails-command